# What is the maximum physical table size in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-design, relational-database, storage

Is there some limit on the maximum total amount of data that can be stored in a single table in Oracle?

I think there shouldn't be because tables are anyways stored as a set of rows and rows can be chained as well. Does such a limit exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Physical Database Limits](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits002.htm#i287915) and [Logical Database Limits](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm#i288032) documentation.

Comment: Logical Limits for 12c https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/logical-database-limits.htm